# Using '?' in route for old URLs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We have a bunch of URLs like this `/order/step1.php?service=999` out there on the Internet.

Do you have to just abandon all of your old links that are published out on the Internet when you migrate to Laravel?

We tried to use `mod_rewrite` to simply rewrite the URL to `/order/step1/999` but because of the .htaccess for Laravel that isn't working.

```
RewriteRule ^/order/step1\.php\?service=([0-9]+)$ /order/step1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

We also tried adding a route into web.php like this:

`Route::get('/step-1.php?service={slug}', 'PageController@step1');`

and that doesn't work either.

We would like to be able to not lose all of our old URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the url is like this:

> /order/step1.php?service=999

The `?service=999` segment can be taken as a query param. So I think this should do the trick:

```
Route::get('order/step-1.php', 'PageController@step1');
```

Then in your controller:

```
# PageController.php

public function step1(Request $request)
{
    $slug = $request->query('service');
    dd($slug) // '999'
}
```

Check the section [Retrieving Input > Retrieving Input From The Query String](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) of the documentation.